# What is English Afternoon tea?

Tags: tea

I googled this, and I couldn't find an answer on the first page of results.

What is English Afternoon tea, and how is it different to English Breakfast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see below from an article on  [teaandcoffee.net](http://www.teaandcoffee.net/0710/tea.htm) .

> Breakfast tea blends tend to contain teas that produce a cup strong and robust enough to “get the body moving” in the morning, allowing you to start your day with a kick. Conversely, afternoon tea blends are designed to be lighter in character and tend to be smoother on the palate, creating the perfect feel for a day winding down.

There is more to read and some very interesting information on the subject. You may want to take a look at the page.